# Showing the X and Y are Independent when their pdf is given

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, proof-explanation, statistical-inference, independence

I am supposed to show that X and Y are independent. I have my suspicions that maybe I should use some sort of ecpectations rule, but I am honestly unsure.

This is as far as I have gotten: $f_{X,Y}({x,y})=\{_{0\ \ \ o.w.}^{1 \ \ \ if \ \ 0<x<1 and 0<y<1}$

I wrote out the the marginal pdfs like so. ( I believe this is correct )

$f_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dy$

and

$f_Y(y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dx$

I will also include a screenshot of the original question for more context.[image: Original Question]

Comment: Do you know the _definition_ of independent random variables?

Comment: It seems like there are some equal signs missing from your equations.

Comment: thanks, corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know the joint PDF of $[X,Y]$, so in this case we can calculate the marginal distributions with the formulas you have given above. (Perhaps there are some exceptions, but those are irrelevant now.)

The PDF of $X$ is
$$f_{X}\left(x\right)=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if}\;x\in\left[0,1\right]\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases},$$

and the PDF of Y is:
$$f_{Y}\left(y\right)=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if}\;y\in\left[0,1\right]\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}.$$

While $$f_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right)=f_{X}\left(x\right)\cdot f_{Y}\left(y\right),$$ therefore $X$ and $Y$ are independent. (We can say $X$ and $Y$ are independent if their joint PDF can be calculated with the products of the two marginal PDF.)

Comment: Sorry...the same answer has been given above, but I haven't noticed while I was writing my own answer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to show that
$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_X(x)f_Y(y) 
$$
for all $(x, y)$. The marginal pdf of $X$ is
$$
f_X(x) = \int f_{X,Y}(x,y)dy = \int1 dy=1,
$$
same for $f_Y(y)$, hence
$$
f_X(x)f_Y(y)  = 1\cdot 1 =1 = f_{X,Y}(x,y)
$$
for $(x, y)$ in $[0,1]^2$, and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Actually, you need to show that $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(y)$ for _all_ $x$ and $y$, not just for $[0,1]^2$.

Comment: Thank you. Corrected.